# Number of ways to pick elements from a set

Tags: combinatorics

How can I show that the number of ways to pick n elements of the set {-1,0,1} where order does not matter is $\frac {(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$? So for example, if $n=2$, {1,-1} is the same as {-1,1}? I think this is the right formula as it works for n=1,2,3..
Thanks in advance

Comment: Search for bars and stars problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to choose $n$ elements from a set of $3$ elements $\{a,b,c\}$. Say you choose $n_a$ copies of $a$, $n_b$ copies of $b$ and $n_c$ copies of $c$. Then, $n_a + n_b + n_c = n$, each unique set of $n_a,n_b,n_c$ is one choice. Therefore we can enumerate these by consider choosing $n_a$ between $0$ and $n$, choosing $n_b$ between 0 and $n - n_a$ and choosing $n_c$ to be $n - n_a - n_b$. This means there are $N = \sum_{n_a = 0}^n \sum_{n_b = 0}^{n-n_a} 1$ ways (as there is no choice left in $n_c$).

Lets evaluate the inner-most sum $ \sum_{n_b = 0}^{n-n_a} 1 = n-n_a + 1$. Then the outer sum becomes $ N = \sum_{n_a = 0}^n ((n+1) - n_a) = (n+1)^2 - \sum_{n_a = 0}^n n_a = (n+1)^2 - \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. (The last sum evaluation is the sum famous performed by Gauss as a child, you can derive this by pairing the terms in the series).

Expanding and combining fractions gives $N = \frac{2(n+1)^2 - n(n+1)}{2} = \frac{(n+1)(2n+2 -n)}{2} = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$ as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

This is known as [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Order your choices increasingly, e.g.

`-1 -1 -1 -1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1`

There are exactly two positions where it changes:

`-1 -1 -1 -1 HERE 0  0  0 HERE 1  1  1  1  1  1  1`

So from the total of $n+2$ positions, we need to choose $2$ where to insert `HERE`

So the answer is $\binom{n+2}{2}=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$

Comment: Or, more technically, combination with repetitions.